# c++ if statement will not end

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to c++ and am not sure if i am explaining this correctly.

I have a piece of code( a function) that does not end when running the whole program.

The purpose of the function is to first generate a random number from 0 to 1. Next if that random number is greater than 0.6, it goes into another function. That function virus_death works perfectly. If the random number is less than 0.6 then it will make the virus point push back into a vector called reached. It will also write the point to a file. However, the statment never stops.

```
void replication(vector<Virus>& virus, int a, int b, double& times, int& iv, 
                 ofstream& data_file, int p, vector<Direction>& direction_v, 
                 vector<Virus>&replicate, int step)
{
    point R,P;

    double replicates  = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
    //how long the virus takes to reach the necleus

    if( replicates>0.6)
    {
        cout<<"No Replication "<<endl;
        virus_death(times, iv, virus,a,b,data_file,p,direction_v, step);
    }
    else if( replicates<=0.6)
    {
        cout<<"Replication"<<endl;

        ofstream tom;
        tom.open("Timing_nuc.dat");

        cout<<"Points"<<endl;
        R.x = virus[p].getx();
        R.y = virus[p].gety();
        R.t = virus[p].gett();

        cout<<"Write to File"<<endl;
        tom<<p+1<<"\t"<<R.x<<"\t"<<R.y<<"\t"<<R.t<<"\n";

        cout<<"New Points"<<endl;
        P.x = a;
        P.y = b;
        P.t = 0;
        cout<<P.x<<"\t"<<P.y<<"\t"<<P.t<<"\n";


        replicate.push_back(P);
        int aspa = replicate.size();
        cout<<"Replication Size:"<<aspa<<endl;
    }           
}
```

can someone please help me determine why once the point is pushed into the vector, it will not leave the function.

the code that calls this function is:

```
void location_of_virus(vector<Virus>&virus,double& times, int& iv,
                        ofstream& data_file, vector<Direction>& direction_v,
                        vector<Virus>&virus_engulf, circle&cell_c, 
                        circle&nuclei_c, vector<Virus>&replicate, int step)
{
    int a;
    int b;

    //int nc,cc,cmc,nci;
    float dis_c, dis_n;

    int virus_size= virus.size();
    //type = "virus";
    for(int i =0; i<virus_size; i++)
    {
        a = virus[i].getx();
        b = virus[i].gety();

        //to check where the virus is in location to the environment
        dis_c = cell_c.distance(a,b);
        dis_n = nuclei_c.distance(a,b);

        if(dis_n < 5)
        {
            location =" Inside Nucleus";
            cout<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<endl;
            data_file<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<"\n";
            replication(virus,a,b,times,iv,data_file,i,direction_v,replicate,step);
        }   
        else if(dis_n ==5)
        {
            location = "Nucleus";
            cout<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<endl;
            data_file<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<"\n";
            nucleus(virus,a,b,times,iv,data_file,i,direction_v,step);

        }
        else if(dis_c <25 && dis_n>5)
        {
            location = "Cytoplasm";
            cout<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<endl;
            data_file<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<"\n";
            cytoplasm(virus,a,b,times,iv,data_file,p,direction_v,step);
        }
        else if(dis_c ==25)
        {
            location = "Cell Membrane";
            cout<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<endl;
            data_file<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<"\n";
            endocytosis(virus,a,b,times,iv, data_file,i,direction_v,virus_engulf,cell_c,nuclei_c);
        }
        else if (((a ==0 || a == 50 || a>0 || a<50)&& (b ==0 || b == 50 || b>0 || b<50)) && dis_c>15)
        {
            location ="Extracellular Matrix";
            cout<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<endl;
            data_file<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<direction_v[i]<<"\t"<<location<<"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            location ="Left the System";
            cout<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<location<<endl;
            data_file<<i+1<<"\t"<<virus[i]<<"\t"<<location<<"\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no loop here.

Comment: Loop? I don't see any loop.

Comment: "Do not try to bend the loop - that's impossible..."

Comment: See http://sscce.org/ to learn how to ask your question in a way that's more likely to get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: What is the point of `vector<point>reached`? You don't seem to use it even though you say you push to it. You actually push into the `replicate` vector.

Comment: sorry i fixed, it I am new to c++ and coding in general.

Comment: It's totally fine that you are new to coding. We just don't see a loop here at all. Is there some other code calling this function repeatedly?

Comment: yes there is a another function that calls the function, but that function called other functions and that aspect of the code works...i will add that part of the code to the question

Comment: `a == 0 || a == 50 || a > 0 || a < 50` <=> `a == 0 || a > 0 || a == 50 || a < 50` <=> `a >= 0 || a <= 50`, which is *always* true.

Comment: Since you're pushing a `Point` into `replicate` which is a vector of `Virus`, I would look into the `Virus` constructor that takes a `Point` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have an infinite recursion somewhere? E.g. maybe `virus_death` calls `location_of_virus` again or so?

Also, you don't really check if `virus[p]` is valid. Maybe add a small safety check if `p` is in its range.

If you mess up your stack for some reason somewhere somehow, all kinds of strange things can happen - also some endless loop.

Comment: just checked there is not infinite recursion and virus[p] is valid.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by messing up my stack somewhere else?

Comment: How did you check that there is no infinite recursion? Btw., what do you see when you go step-by-step in a debugger? Messing up the stack happens when you write a the wrong memory address which happens to be the stack. Tools like valgrind might detect that.